# Disable support for Random Address for LE Advertising in Bluez 5.31

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspbian, bluez

I am using a BT/LE dual mode dongle to run in LE only mode with custom manufacture data (to act as OOB medium). 
The functionality works well in ubuntu desktop system (KERNEL - 3.13.0-57-generic) but fails in raspbian (KERNEL - 4.0.9+). My guess that it has something to do with kernel implementation of hci but I am not sure.

In Ubuntu, running the dual mode dongle in LE only mode I can see my mac address using hcitool (lescan). But if I run it in raspbian I can see random address advertising rather than public address advertising.

Also using static-addr command from btmgmt is not working. (still getting random address).

So, How do I disable the random address or how can I use the public address instead of random address?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed the functionality of kernel bluetooth driver. The new implementation has the random address functionality. But this can be fixed with btmgmt by giving following commands.

1. Turn off power ( needed to disable classic BT)
   power off
2. Turn on le ( you must have one controller so that you can remove classic BT controller)

   le on
3. Turn off bredr

   bredr off
4. Turn on power

   power on
5. Set connectable ( this will make hci driver to use public address instead of random address)

   connectable on
6. Set discoverable ( without this, bluez will discard the device hence will not be available through dbus api. Unless you change bluez implementation)

   discov on
7. Start advertising

   advertising on

Hope this helps

Comment: There must be a way to turn address randomization off without changing to connectable. Maybe its just an issue of btmgmt, it sets alot of parameters automatically. privacy on/off didnt have any influence on that behaviour?

Comment: @Dominik Gebhart setting privacy to off didn't had any effect on the random address behavior. AFAIK, btmgmt does not set these parameters automatically. Infact it uses function used in bluez daemon e,g (scanning, connecting).

Comment: Yes you are right, i went through the code just now, it uses the bluez mgmt api referenced in doc/mgmt-api.txt. Rather confusing all that. I have an application using non-connectable advertisements sent on short interval where i use the public address for lookup in another application. Setting those parameters directly with `hcitool` works well. I was hoping `btmgmt` would allow the same range of access to those settings, but it looks like it doesnt.. A pity.

Comment: Just to clarify though, the initial issue must've come from setting the parameters with `btmgmt`, it changes the advertisement configuration in that way. If one needs more fine grained access to the advetisement settings one needs to fall back on direct HCI commands as specified in the Core specification. Bluez `hcitool` allows you to send these directly.

Comment: @DominikGebhart Just FYI, hcitool directly uses kernel driver's ioctls (libbluetooth); it does not depend on the bluetoothd (i,e bluez). On the other hand btmgmt directly depends on the bluetoothd. These two are incompatible. So, for example, if you start a scan request using hcitool/hciconfig; it is highly likely that you will not be able to get the response via d-bus / btmgmt. Which may make things complex for some trivial operation (e,g - using hcidump to get manufacture data, while they are available through dbus). But for now dbus api is very unstable and many functionality is lacking.

Comment: @DominikGebhart althought btmgmt/dbus-api's performance is poor compare to hci*** tools (even though they are recommended by the bluez devs over hci*** tools). Performancewise: hci*** tools > btmgmt > dbus-api

Answer (score 3):

It seems this is triggered by an activated *privacy feature*.

See section `10.7.1 Privacy Feature in a Peripheral` of the [Core 4.0 Specification](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=229737).

> Support of the privacy feature in a Peripheral depends on the presence
>   and the value of two characteristics: Peripheral Privacy Flag
>   characteristic as defined in Section 12.3 and the Reconnection Address
>   characteristic as defined in Sec- tion 12.4. When the Peripheral
>   Privacy Flag characteristic is set to 1, privacy is enabled (also
>   known as privacy enabled Peripheral).

Also check `12.3 PERIPHERAL PRIVACY FLAG CHARACTERISTIC` for details on the Attribute handle and value, maybe you can spot it in your device.

Why there is a difference between Ubuntu and Raspi, i can only guess that the version is not exactly the same.

You could also try to check with `btmon` if you can spot any differences in the hci commands sent to your bluetooth modules on advertisement configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The version is exactly same. Infact it is compiled from same source with exactly same option. My guess is that kernel HCI driver implementation might be different. Thanks again for the pointer I will disable the privacy using btmgmt and will get back to you.

Comment: Oh right, i just see we can set/unset with `btmgmt`! Great!